# Amcharts chartCursor show at last position

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, amcharts

Amcharts: Force-show balloon over specific point.
I want chart cursor on last date in chart.

**Please see my console in image. i have generated error.**

Here is a amcharts doc link: https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/force-show-balloon-over-specific-data-point/
Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/JdTuA/
But i am unable to do it. Here is my code and error is also pasted in image. Please guide. [image]

```
<script>
(function () {
    var chartWeight = AmCharts.makeChart("{{ div }}", {
        "type": "serial",
        "theme": "light",
        "dataProvider": {{ data.json|raw }},
        "creditsPosition": "top-right",
        "synchronizeGrid":false,
        "zoomOutText": "",
        "valueAxes": [
            {
                "id":"v_kg",
                //"title": "Bodyweight in kg",
                //"title": "Körpergewicht in kg",
                "axisColor": "#2A3B55",
                "axisThickness": 0,
                "gridAlpha": 0,
                "offset": 0,
                "axisAlpha": 0,
                "position": "left",
                "labelsEnabled": false,
                "minimum": {{ 0.99 * data.chartsOptions.all.minKg }},
                "maximum": {{ 1.01 * data.chartsOptions.all.maxKg }},
                "autoGridCount": false,
                "gridCount": 200,
                "strictMinMax": true
            },
            {
                "id":"v_ratio",
                //"title": "Bodyfat in %",
                //"title": "Körperfett in %",
                "axisColor": "#A46A1F",
                "axisThickness": 0,
                "gridAlpha": 0,
                "offset": 0,
                "axisAlpha": 0,
//                "position": "right",
                "labelsEnabled": false,
                "minimum": {{ (0.9 * data.chartsOptions.all.minFat)|round(1) }},
                "maximum": {{ (1.05 * data.chartsOptions.all.maxFat)|round(1) }},
                "autoGridCount": false,
                "gridCount": 200,
                "strictMinMax": true
            },
            {
                "id":"v_lean",
                //"title": "Lean Mass in kg",
                //"title": "Muskelmasse in kg",
                "axisColor": "#80B3FF",
                "axisThickness": 0,
                "gridAlpha": 0,
                "offset": 0,
                "axisAlpha": 0,
//                "position": "right",
                "labelsEnabled": false
            },
        ],
        "graphs": [{
            "valueAxis": "v_kg",
            "lineColor": "#2A3B55",
            "lineThickness": 2,
            "title": "Bodyweight",
            "valueField": "kgBodyweight",
            "fillAlphas": 0,
            "balloonText": "Weight: [[value]]kg",
            "legendValueText": "[[value]]kg",
        }, {
            //"valueAxis": "v_lean",
            "valueAxis": "v_kg",
            "lineColor": "#80B3FF",
            "lineThickness": 2,
            "title": "Lean Mass",
            "valueField": "kgLeanmass",
            "fillAlphas": 0,
            "balloonText": "Lean Mass: [[value]]kg",
            "legendValueText": "[[value]]kg"
        }, {
            "valueAxis": "v_ratio",
            "lineColor": "#A46A1F",
            "lineThickness": 2,
            "title": "Fat",
            "valueField": "ratioBodyfat",
            "fillAlphas": 0,
            "balloonText": "Fat: [[value]]%",
            "legendValueText": "[[value]]%"
        }],
        "chartCursor": {
            "cursorPosition": 'mouse',
            "leaveCursor": true,
            "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
        },
        "chartScrollbar": {
            "selectedBackgroundColor": "#7F7F7F",
            "backgroundColor": "#e9e9e9",
            "offset": 12,
            "selectedBackgroundAlpha": 1,
            "backgroundAlpha": 1
        },
        "categoryField": "date",
        "categoryAxis": {
            "parseDates": true,
            "axisColor": "#DADADA",
            "minorGridEnabled": true,
            "startOnAxis": true,
            "gridAlpha": 0.07,
        },
        "export": {
            "enabled": false,
        },
        "legend": {
            "useGraphSettings": true,
        },

    });

    chartCursor = new AmCharts.ChartCursor();

    var date1 = new Date();
    chartCursor.showCursorAt(date1);



    chartWeight.addListener("dataUpdated", function () {
        chartWeight.zoomToIndexes(chartWeight.dataProvider.length - 60, chartWeight.dataProvider.length);
    });
})();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new chart cursor object you created is not attached to a chart, which is why it's complaining about an undefined categoryAxis. When translating the OO-based demos to the makeChart/JSON method, you only need to call the method directly from the chart object since the JSON structure maps directly to how the chart is structured internally. Rather than create a new object, just call `yourChartObject.chartCursor.showCursorAt(<your category value here>)`. In this situation, you're better off doing this in the `init` event so the chart will be fully instantiated before you call the method:

```
AmCharts.makeChart("...", {
  // ...
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "init",
    "method": function(e) {
       e.chart.showCursorAt(/* your date value */);
    }
  }]
})
```

Demo below:

```js
(function() {
  var chartWeight = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "dataProvider": getData(),
    "creditsPosition": "top-right",
    "synchronizeGrid": false,
    "zoomOutText": "",
    "valueAxes": [{
        "id": "v_kg",
        //"title": "Bodyweight in kg",
        //"title": "Körpergewicht in kg",
        "axisColor": "#2A3B55",
        "axisThickness": 0,
        "gridAlpha": 0,
        "offset": 0,
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "position": "left",
        "labelsEnabled": false,
        //  "minimum": {{ 0.99 * data.chartsOptions.all.minKg }},
        //  "maximum": {{ 1.01 * data.chartsOptions.all.maxKg }},
        "autoGridCount": false,
        "gridCount": 200,
        "strictMinMax": true
      },
      {
        "id": "v_ratio",
        //"title": "Bodyfat in %",
        //"title": "Körperfett in %",
        "axisColor": "#A46A1F",
        "axisThickness": 0,
        "gridAlpha": 0,
        "offset": 0,
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        //                "position": "right",
        "labelsEnabled": false,
        //   "minimum": {{ (0.9 * data.chartsOptions.all.minFat)|round(1) }},
        //   "maximum": {{ (1.05 * data.chartsOptions.all.maxFat)|round(1) }},
        "autoGridCount": false,
        "gridCount": 200,
        "strictMinMax": true
      },
      {
        "id": "v_lean",
        //"title": "Lean Mass in kg",
        //"title": "Muskelmasse in kg",
        "axisColor": "#80B3FF",
        "axisThickness": 0,
        "gridAlpha": 0,
        "offset": 0,
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        //                "position": "right",
        "labelsEnabled": false
      },
    ],
    "graphs": [{
      "valueAxis": "v_kg",
      "lineColor": "#2A3B55",
      "lineThickness": 2,
      "title": "Bodyweight",
      "valueField": "kgBodyweight",
      "fillAlphas": 0,
      "balloonText": "Weight: [[value]]kg",
      "legendValueText": "[[value]]kg",
    }, {
      //"valueAxis": "v_lean",
      "valueAxis": "v_kg",
      "lineColor": "#80B3FF",
      "lineThickness": 2,
      "title": "Lean Mass",
      "valueField": "kgLeanmass",
      "fillAlphas": 0,
      "balloonText": "Lean Mass: [[value]]kg",
      "legendValueText": "[[value]]kg"
    }, {
      "valueAxis": "v_ratio",
      "lineColor": "#A46A1F",
      "lineThickness": 2,
      "title": "Fat",
      "valueField": "ratioBodyfat",
      "fillAlphas": 0,
      "balloonText": "Fat: [[value]]%",
      "legendValueText": "[[value]]%"
    }],
    "chartCursor": {
      "cursorPosition": 'mouse',
      "leaveCursor": true,
      "valueBalloonsEnabled": true,
    },
    "chartScrollbar": {
      "selectedBackgroundColor": "#7F7F7F",
      "backgroundColor": "#e9e9e9",
      "offset": 12,
      "selectedBackgroundAlpha": 1,
      "backgroundAlpha": 1
    },
    "categoryField": "date",
    "categoryAxis": {
      "parseDates": true,
      "axisColor": "#DADADA",
      "minorGridEnabled": true,
      "startOnAxis": true,
      "gridAlpha": 0.07,
    },
    "export": {
      "enabled": false,
    },
    "legend": {
      "useGraphSettings": true,
    },
    "listeners": [{
      "event": "init",
      "method": function(e) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        date.setDate(date.getDate() - Math.floor(Math.random() * 20))
        e.chart.chartCursor.showCursorAt(date);
      }
    }]

  });



  chartWeight.addListener("dataUpdated", function() {
    chartWeight.zoomToIndexes(chartWeight.dataProvider.length - 60, chartWeight.dataProvider.length);
  });

  function getData() {
    var firstDate = new Date();
    firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 100);
    firstDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 120; ++i) {
      var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
      newDate.setDate(i);
      var dataItem = {
        "date": newDate,
        "kgLeanmass": Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 40),
        "kgBodyweight": Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 60)
      };
      dataItem.ratioBodyfat = parseFloat((100 * ((dataItem.kgBodyweight - dataItem.kgLeanmass) / dataItem.kgBodyweight)).toFixed(2));
      data.push(dataItem);
    }
    return data;
  }
})();
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 362px;"></div>
```

Comment: Hello @xorspark Yes, it worked in most charts, but on few charts i have applied setTimeout of 1500 miliseconds in function. Then it worked.
Anyway i got result. Thank you very much.

Comment: some time i see chart cursor line is not displaying, most of time it displaying. So is it a loading time issue?

Comment: `makeChart` is asynchronous so if you're not using an event then it's basically a coin-flip as to whether it  will work consistently without using a timeout. If you're still havnig a problem with `init`, use `drawn` instead but set a flag so that you don't constantly show the cursor on data update if your chart updates itself periodically (unless you actually want that to happen).

Comment: ```drawn``` works. I did not understand much you last line message. but it helped me. Thanks!